# Multiple values in is_protected_meta()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to hide multiple custom fields from my wordpress backend using is_protected_meta()

This code works:

```
add_filter('is_protected_meta', 'my_is_protected_meta_filter', 10, 2);
function my_is_protected_meta_filter($protected, $meta_key) {
return $meta_key == 'pyre_custom1' ? true : $protected;
}
```

But it is not working when i am trying to pass multiple values..My code is:

```
add_filter('is_protected_meta', 'my_is_protected_meta_filter', 10, 2);
function my_is_protected_meta_filter($protected, $meta_key) {

return array($meta_key == 'pyre_custom1' ? true : $protected,$meta_key == 'pyre_custom2' ? true : $protected,$meta_key == 'pyre_custom3' ? true : $protected);
}
```

This seem to hide the full custom fields section. How can i make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
if( in_array($meta_key, array('pyre_custom1', 'pyre_custom2', 'pyre_custom3')) ){
    return true;
}
return $protected;
```